# How to remove a partition within a VDI file?

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, virtualization

I recently created a new virtual machine (Linux) that shares the same VDI as an existing virtual machine (WinXP). The installation of the OS on the new virtual machine aborted because there wasn't enough space.

How can I delete the Linux partition on the VDI so that I'm only left with the WinXP partition?

Answer (score 0):

Boot any system inside the virtual machine (either from the other partition(s), or from a CD/DVD), and use any standard partitioning software.